# How to set letter spacing in Java Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

In CSS, there is a *letter-spacing* property that we can use to increase spacing per letter in a word.

Is there a way I can increase a letter space or text space? I was hoping I can increase the space of the text in a field.

Comment: Could you please add some code as well

Comment: I used the Netbeans GUI Builder so I just drag and drop instead. It's Java Swing. There's a solution below I'd try.

Comment: *"Is there a way I can increase a letter space or text space in **Java Swing using Netbeans IDE?**"* The GUI is irrelevant. If there's a solution to this, it is in the Java code itself. *"I used the Netbeans GUI Builder so I just drag and drop instead."* ..and this 'excuse for not providing code' is yet another reason not to become so dependent on an IDE. Are you learning Java or learning a software tool? Dump the GUI builder and learn how to code GUI's using .. Java code. This will serve you well in future, and is more likely to get help *right now.* Voting to close for lack of a [mre].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a text.");
        Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.TRACKING, 0.5);

        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(attributes));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
    });
}
```

Result:

[image: preview]

Comment: First time I saw _this_ wonderful solution. It merits adding a small techical explanation, especially as you already added an image. And add a line break in `attributes = ...`

Comment: A link to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#TRACKING) would be useful here.  Code dumps with no explanation are not good answers.